# Swagger - Error in deploying spring webflux boot war in tomcat with swagger boot starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, swagger, spring-webflux

I am trying to deploy the spring webflux boot war in apache tomcat server.
On including the below dependency to add swagger functionality in build gradle,

compile 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'

The war deployment is failing with below error

```
Failed to introspect Class [springfox.boot.starter.autoconfigure.SwaggerUiWebMvcConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@6a78afa0
]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680  
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        ... 67 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        ... 78 more
```

It is expecting org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer to be present on classpath but since this is built on spring webflux, it doesn't have it on path.

Followed springfox documentation and demos github repo for reference

https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#gradle

https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/boot-webflux

The demo repo starts the app as spring boot jar but I need to deploy as war on server.

Did anyone face this issue while deploying the spring webflux boot war on server?
Could someone please help what I'm missing on my configuration?

Edit: Added build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
  id 'war'
  id 'groovy'
}


ext {
  set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR6")
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.4', ext: 'pom'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.3'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.3'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.13.3'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy'
  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
  }
  testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '2.0-M2-groovy-2.5'
  testCompile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test', version: '3.3.8.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your implementation and your pom.xml, `Could someone please help what I'm missing on my configuration` well you havn't posted it

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have added the build.gradle in question. Kindly review and let me know. Removed unrelated dependencies from gradle file and posted it here.